# python executable error (mac os)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I distributed a python executable compressed by cx_freeze

my users are getting this error while running the python exec 
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python

works fine for me when I run "which python3" in terminal I get /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

is there a way i can add something to thr script repack it as executable and distribute it